# Difference between accessing non-static data member using scope resolution operator and this (keyword) in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the subtle nuances between two ways of accessing non-static data members in C++: one using the scope resolution operator `::` and the other using the `this` keyword. Here's my code:

```cpp
class Number {
    int x;
public:
    void setX(const int x) {
        Number::x = x; // This line works, but then how's it different from "this->x = x"
    }
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
};
```

I'd like to understand the practical and conceptual differences between these two approaches.

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Number::x compared to this->x in terms of readability, maintainability, and potential risks?
2. Are there any scenarios where one approach is preferred over the other, and if so, what are they?

Comment: It's a syntax to help with inheritance. There are cases when you need to use a member of a parent class, then you can use the scope resolution syntax like that. The most common example is for overridden member functions, that also calls the same member function in a parent class.

Comment: " I thought that non-static data members should be accessed through instances of the class, like this->x" `this->` is optional most of the time, just like in `getX` where you write `return x;` rather than `return this->x;`. This is of course not an answer, but just a hint that you are conflating two separate aspects

Comment: There is no difference in this case. `this->` is implicit in the `Number::x = x;` line, which is in effect `this->Number::x = x`, and the `Number::` part is redundant as there is no ambiguity.